# Existing ways to call Java methods from AIR app (Android)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, ane

I am familiar with Air Native Extensions (ANE). Is there are any other ways to call Java methods from AIR for Android application?

I'm almost 100% sure it's not, but I want to ask anyway to be 100%:
Is there any way to somehow integrate Flash project into Eclipse Java application project and build Java APK containing Flash game?

Thanks

Comment: Bundling .jars and exposing methods via an ANE is the only way to do it.

Comment: Thank you @RobertN. I couldn't find any other way on net. Just wanted to ask here and be sure.

Comment: I'd love to hear it also if there was ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way to call native Java functions in Adobe Air application its Adobe Navite Extensions, and here some tutorial to get started with it: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html